# <f:attribute name="id"> throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.setValueExpression

Tags: jsf, attributes, illegalargumentexception

I have a select one menu with a vaildator as following:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{planning.formuleCremation}"
     converter="#{formuleCremationConverter}" 
     validator="#{PlanningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{beanPlanningSalleAppareil.formules}"
         var="formule"
         itemLabel="#{formule.alias}"
         itemValue="#{formule}" />
  <f:attribute name="id" value="#{planning.id}" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I'm trying to pass an attribute with selectOneMenu so that I can retrieve it in `PlanningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator` as following:

```
public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException {

     //Retrieve the attribute id passed with the current component
     int id = (int) uic.getAttributes().get("id");
     Object selectedObject = null;

     //Current Planning
     PlanningSalleAppareil planningSalleAppareil = planningSalleAppareilService.trouver(id);

     if(planningSalleAppareil.getAppareil() != null)
         selectedObject = planningSalleAppareil.getAppareil();
     if(planningSalleAppareil.getSalle() != null)
         selectedObject = planningSalleAppareil.getSalle();

     planningSalleAppareil.setFormuleCremation((FormuleCremation) o);

     if(selectedObject != null){
         String errorMessage = planningSalleAppareilService.validPlanningSalleAppareil(planningSalleAppareil,selectedObject);
         if(!errorMessage.equals("1")){
             FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(errorMessage);
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
             throw new ValidatorException(msg);
         }
     }
 }
```

But this doesn't work and it throws me :  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.setValueExpression`

I get this error when I only add: `<f:attribute name="id" value="#{planning.id}" />` to the selectOneMenu, otherwise the validator is working.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively,

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    <f:attribute name="id" value="#{planning.id}" />
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

does exactly the same as:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="#{planning.id}" ...>
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem with this approach is that JSF does not allow setting a render time value expression as `id` attribute of the component. Moreover, you'd better not override/reuse a standard JSF component attribute for different/internal purposes.

Rename it to something else, e.g. `planningId`.

```
<f:attribute name="planningId" ... />
```

Comment: I actually had a problem with the validator after that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228424/validator-throws-javax-el-elexception-identity-does-not-reference-a-methodexpre